# Knockout nested view model

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm stuck with what must be a simple fix. I am using knockout.js with nested view models, and all seems fine except that my remove function is not working correctly. It appears to be binding correctly, however it is not fired when I click remove.

Why nested view models? Long story, but essentially a lot of stuff is required to be on one page!

So here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<section class="mini-form-container">
    <form data-bind="submit: repeatGuest.addDate">
        <input type="date" data-bind="value: repeatGuest.previousStay"/>
        <button type="submit" class="button-secondary ">Add date</button>
    </form>
    <div data-bind="foreach: repeatGuest.dates, visible: repeatGuest.dates().length > 0">
        <div>
            <input data-bind="value: date" disabled="disabled"  />
            <a data-bind="click: $parent.removeDate">Remove</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section>
    <div data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data)"></div>
</section>
```

**Javascript**

```
function RepeatGuest() {
    /// <summary>Child View Model</summary>
    this.dates = ko.observableArray();
    this.previousStay = ko.observable();
}

RepeatGuest.prototype.addDate = function () {
        var self = this.repeatGuest;
        if (self.previousStay()) {
            self.dates.push({
                date: self.previousStay()
            });
        }
    };

RepeatGuest.prototype.removeDate = function (date) {
    this.dates.remove(date);
}

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.repeatGuest = new RepeatGuest();
}
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

And here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6Px4M/2/

So why isn't my remove function getting fired?

*Possible side question: is nested view models the wrong path to take in knockout, there doesn't seem to much info on this?*

Answer (score 25, accepted):

One of the best ways to work with a nested model like this is to use the `with` binding.  You can do:

```
<div data-bind="with: repeatGuest">
   ...
</div>
```

Now, the scope is your `repeatGuest` and you can bind directly against its properties.

The issue with your `remove` function is related to the value of `this` and who `$parent` is at that time.  Functions are executed with a value of `this` that is equal to the current scope.  When your remove function is bound, the scope is one of the objects in the `date` array.

The typically way to handle this is to make sure that your function is bound to always use the correct value of `this`.  This could be done in the binding (very ugly) like:

```
<a data-bind="click: $parent.repeatGuest.removeDate.bind($parent.repeatGuest)">Remove</a>
```

A better option is to bind it in the view model, in your `RepeatGuest` constructor:

```
this.removeDate = this.removeDate.bind(this);
```

This allows the implementation to live on the prototype and overwrites it on each instance with a wrapper that forces the correct value of `this`.  Alternatively, if you do not put it on the prototype, then you can use the `var self = this;` pattern and use `self` in the handler.

http://jsfiddle.net/cNdJj/

Comment: I prefer the `var self = this` pattern. Its easier for me to just always use `self` than to remember to bind functions. It also looks cleaner, imo.

Comment: this good stuff, +1 from me, but there was a more fundamental issue that the function was never being run since he stuck it on the prototype.  Though if he followed all of your steps that would get resolved too.

Comment: @Tyrsius - I was trying to show how you can still place the implementation of the function on the prototype. `self` is a fine pattern.

Comment: @ben336 - the issue was not that the function was on the prototype, but that he was trying to bind against it on the view model (`$parent` in that case) rather than on the repeatGuest object itself (`$parent.repeatGuest`).

Comment: @RPNiemeyer yes you're right.  Too much typing, not enough thinking there for me.  Your explanation was much better, which is why I upvoted it :)

Comment: Is there another way to specify the remove function without needing to include the line **this.removeDate = this.removeDate.bind(this);** which feels hacky. I could take it off the prototype but then the function would be a new instance on each RepeatGuest instance, so would be loosing the benefit of the putting it on the prototype.

Comment: There are a few options that are not much more attractive than binding in the view model.  You can bind in the data binding string itself, like I showed in the answer (`$parent.repeatGuest.removeDate.bind($parent.repeatGuest)`), but is just as ugly.  You can call the function anonymously in the data-bind like `click: function() { $parent.removeDate($data); }`, but that is equally hacky.  Personally, I have a plugin to do delegated event handling here: https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-delegatedEvents, which makes it unnecessary.  Sample (using `with`): http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/mUxYK/

Answer (score 4):

The binding won't access the function on the wrong prototype.   You're binding to the viewModel, not to the RepeatGuest object right now.

It works if you set it as a local function:

http://jsfiddle.net/6Px4M/3/

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.repeatGuest = new RepeatGuest();
    self.removeDate = function (date) {
        self.repeatguest.dates.remove(date);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, this is how I had it originally. However my viewModel became massive and I was trying to refactor it's size down. Is there any other way to get the remove function out of the view model?

Comment: Sure, you can always pull it out and just set the `self.removeDate` to the function name.

Comment: @RPNiemeyer's solution is more complete though.