# Knockout nested foreach add and remove not working

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I'm having troubles adding to and removing from inside a nested foreach. In this example, we have a House which has many Rooms. Each Room has many pieces of furniture. With this code so far, I can get the data to display properly and can add and remove Rooms, but I cannot add or remove Furniture.

**HTML**

```
//Other House fields work as expected above this section

<div data-bind='foreach: rooms'>
    <button type="button" data-bind='visible: $root.rooms().length > 1, click: $root.removeRoom'> Remove Room </button>

    <p> Room Name</p>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: name"></input>

    //with: appears to work the same as a foreach -- neither seem to work
    <div data-bind="with: furnitures">
        <button type="button" data-bind='click: $root.rooms().furnitures().removeFurniture'> Remove Furniture </button>
        <p> Furniture Name</p>
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: name"></input>
    </div>
    <button type="button" data-bind='click: $root.rooms().furnitures().addFurniture'> Add Furniture </button>
</div>   

<button type="button" data-bind='click: $root.addRoom'> Add Room </button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var HouseModel = function(rooms) {

    var self = this;
    self.rooms = ko.observableArray(rooms);

    // Not sure what to put here for Furniture because each room array item has an array of many furnitures

    // ROOM MANAGEMENT ==========================
    self.addRoom = function() {
        self.rooms.push({
            name:"",
            furnitures[]: ""
        });
    };

    self.removeRoom = function(room) {
        self.rooms.remove(room);
    };

            // FURNITURE MANAGEMENT ==========================
            // Not sure where this goes
            self.addFurniture = function() {
                self.furnitures.push({
                    name: ""
                });
            };

            self.removeFurniture = function(furniture) {
                self.furnitures.remove(furniture);
            };
};

var viewModel = new HouseModel(rooms); // rooms are the pre-existing rooms and their furniture, in JSON format
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

The main problems with this are probably to do with the context of the data-bind of the buttons, and the way the model has been coded. Something is missing or wrong.

Thoughts are appreciated.

**UPDATE**
This is a fiddle of the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/zhLf1n61/

Resources:

- [Knockout nested view model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15163354/knockout-nested-view-model) (this example is different because it does not have nested view models)
- [Knockout.JS official -working with collections](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/collections.html) (I found this to be difficult to apply to my situation)

Comment: Can you also include the Room model as well as that is where a AddFuniture would make most sense for what you are trying to do.  Perhaps even a jsfiddle would be a good idea as well

Comment: That's the thing. There is no Room model; there is only a House model. So when the data gets passed in, it is a House object, with an array of Rooms, and each Room has an array of Furnitures. If you're implying that there should be another model (the Room one), that would certainly make sense, but my understanding is that when using Knockout, one model per page is desirable. Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: @Max There is nothing wrong with having multiple view models per page. Especially if those view models are modular reusable pieces of code.

Comment: @Max I added button binding examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated javascript...

Main entry point is the HouseModel... Houses have Rooms (and methods for removing adding them) and Rooms have Furniture (with methods for adding and removing them). It's all about encapsulation and scope.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/zqwom7kd/

```
var initialData = [{
    "name": "Living Room",
        "furnitures": [{
        "name": "Bookshelf",
            "size": "Medium"
    }]
}, {
    "name": "Bedroom",
        "furnitures": [{
        "name": "Bed",
            "size": "Large"
    }, {
        "name": "Night Table",
            "size": "Small"
    }, {
        "name": "Jacuzzi",
            "size": "Large"
    }]
}];
var Furniture = function(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable('');
    self.size = ko.observable('');
    if (typeof data !== 'undefined') {
        self.name(data.name);
        self.size(data.size);
    }
}
var Room = function(name, furnitures) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable(name);
    self.furnitures = ko.observableArray([]);
    if (typeof furnitures !== 'undefined') {
        $.each(furnitures, function(i, el) {
            self.furnitures.push(new Furniture({name: el.name, size: el.size}));
        });
    }
    self.removeFurniture = function(furniture) {
        self.furnitures.remove(furniture);
    };
    self.addFurniture = function() {
        console.log("added");
        self.furnitures.push(new Furniture({name: '', size: ''}));
    };
};

var HouseModel = function (rooms) {
    var self = this;
    self.save = function() {
        console.log("do stuff");
    };
    self.lastSavedJson = ko.observable('');
    self.rooms = ko.observableArray([]);
    if (typeof rooms !== 'undefined') {
        $.each(rooms, function(i, el) {
            self.rooms.push(new Room(el.name, el.furnitures));
        });
    }

    self.addRoom = function(name) {
        self.rooms.push(new Room(name));
    };

    self.removeRoom = function (room) {
        self.rooms.remove(room);
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new HouseModel(initialData));
```

**HTML**

```
<h2>House Components</h2>

<div id='roomsList'>
    <table class='roomsEditor'>
        <tr>
            <th>Room Name</th>
            <th>Furnitures</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: rooms">
            <tr class="well">
                <td valign="top">
                    <input type="text" data-bind='value: name' />
                    <div> <button class="btn btn-danger" data-bind='click: $root.rooms.removeRoom'>Remove Room</button>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tbody data-bind="foreach: furnitures">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" data-bind='value: name' />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" data-bind='value: size' />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <button class="btn btn-danger" data-bind='click: $parent.removeFurniture'>Delete Furniture</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <button class="btn btn-success" data-bind='click: addFurniture'>Add Furniture</button>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<p>
    <button class="btn btn-success" data-bind='click: $root.rooms.addRoom'>Add Room</button>
    <button data-bind='click: save, enable: rooms().length > 0'>Save to JSON</button>
</p>
<textarea data-bind='value: lastSavedJson' rows='5' cols='60' disabled='disabled'></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately this does not work. It displays the data, but the buttons do not work. Maybe the button call contexts are wrong? I tried `$root.rooms().addFurniture` and also `$data.addFurniture`

Comment: really need to compose Rooms and Furnitures as objects that don't just have properties, but functions.

Comment: You're probably right. I saw your other post here  `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29572088/multiple-arrays-in-one-knockout-js-viewmodel/29609645#29609645` and will be sure to try that.

Comment: Yeah... very similar. Redid the code above to show another approach that looks more like that.

Comment: I implemented the advice and here is a fiddle `http://jsfiddle.net/zhLf1n61/`. As I mentioned to CrimsonChris, It works fine when there is no house involved and there is only rooms and furniture, but once I try to put the rooms and furniture in the house, I can no longer manipulate the furniture. @ brettwgreen

Comment: Updated here... this construct works pretty well. There's a tension between creating separate view models vs. object models. In this case, these are nested objects... you don't want separate viewModels in this case in my opinion. http://jsfiddle.net/brettwgreen/zhLf1n61/2/

Comment: Note how the scoping works in concert with the view and it's for loops... when I'm inside the Room scope, I can call addFurniture directly, but inside the Furniture scope, I must call $parent.removeFurniture to get to that method which rightly belongs at the Room level (Furnitures can't remove themselves).

Comment: Thanks! Your solution worked fully after I made a few minor changes. I tried to edit the post, but I think it got rejected. Updated fiddle is here `http://jsfiddle.net/zqwom7kd/` However, there is one last thing. `Add Room` does not work as expected. @brettwgreen

Comment: Got to get your scope right... avoid specifying scope params unless necessary. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/brettwgreen/zqwom7kd/2/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a place to start. As @Nathan Fisher mentioned, it would make sense to create a `Room` and potentially even a `Furniture` class.

HTML

```
<button data-bind="click: addRoom"></button>
<div data-bind='foreach: rooms'>
    <button data-bind="click: $parent.removeRoom"></button>
    <button data-bind="click: $parent.addFurnitureToRoom"></button>
    <div data-bind="foreach: furnitures">
        <button data-bind="click: $parents[1].removeFurnitureFromRoom.bind($root, $data, $parent)"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function HouseViewModel (rooms) {
    var self = this;
    this.rooms = ko.observableArray(rooms || []);

    this.addRoom = function () {
        self.rooms.push({
            name: ko.observable(''),
            furnitures: ko.observableArray(),
        });
    };

    this.removeRoom = function (room) {
        self.rooms.remove(room);
    };

    this.addFurnitureToRoom = function (room) {
        room.furnitures.push({
            name: ko.observable(''),
        });
    };

    self.removeFurnitureFromRoom = function (furniture, room) {
        room.furnitures.remove(furniture);
    };
};
```

Comment: This will work, but it should be noted that the primary problem is that furnitures needs to be an observableArray. That's why your original solution didn't work.

Comment: Here is a fiddle of what I mean. `http://jsfiddle.net/zhLf1n61/` It works fine when there is no house involved and there is only rooms and furniture, but once I try to put the rooms and furniture in the house, I can no longer manipulate the furniture

Comment: @Max Make sure you are getting the correct arguments passed to the add/remove furniture. I've updated the bindings above.

Comment: Note that this does NOT use a RoomsViewModel. If you move the add/remove furniture functions into the rooms then the bindings will need to be different.